# Filter one table using another as reference

Tags: excel, vba

I monitor my study habits using excel. I have a table like

Table 1:

```
| Start Time | End Time | Date   | Pages |
|------------|----------|--------|-------|
| 07:40:00   | 08:00:00 | 12 May | 12    |
| 08:13:00   | 08:25:00 | 12 May | 5     |
| 08:40:00   | 08:55    | 12 May | 8     |
```

As you can see, there are intervals in between the end time of one row and the start time of the next row. That's because I'll generally get distracted by the Internet. I know how to get Google Chrome history  into a table of the format -

Table 2:

```
| Time Visited | URL Visited               |
|--------------|---------------------------|
| 08:03:00     | https://www.reddit.com/   |
| 08:08:00     | https://www.facebook.com/ |
| 08:28:00     | https://www.youtube.com/  |
| 08:32:00     | https://www.facebook.com/ |
| 08:34:00     | https://www.reddit.com/   |
```

With obviously a lot more URLs. I'm looking for a way in which if I click on a row in Table 1 (in excel), Table 2 filters down to the websites visited between the `End Time` of that row and the `Start Time` of the next row. I'm an excel noob and have been avoiding VBA for as long as possible, but I'd be grateful if someone could provide me with any solution. Also are there any data structures like Pivot Tables etc. that can be used over here?

Thanks

Comment: `| 09:00:00  | http://stackoverflow.com/help/ |`

Comment: @Ambie, funny, and quick. And for that matter, to the point. Waivek, although it's an interesting project, you are supposed to show what you've tried.

Comment: So I tried to make a Pivot Table from both the tables but that wasn't possible. I also tried using an Excel Array Formula using Aggregate and an If inside it but that was resulting in one cell per row which isn't what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Spent the whole night learning VBA. Solved the problem!

Solution Sheet (Go to the second sheet named "MySheet") -

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx5DxTdpRXyyekZlenlxSTZsTW8/view?usp=sharing

Code (which is included in excel) =

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        Dim name As String
        Dim triggerCol As String
        Dim tableToFilter As String
        Dim ClickedInTable As Boolean

        Dim lowerColName As String
        Dim lower As String
        Dim upperColName As String
        Dim upper As String

        Dim colToFilterRelativeIndex As Integer
        Dim colToFilter As String

        Dim inHeader As Boolean
        Dim inTriggerCol As Boolean

        Dim lowerIsHeader As Boolean

        Dim lowerCell As Range
        Dim upperCell As Range

        tableToFilter = "Olive"
        colToFilter = "Time Visited"

        lowerColName = "End time"
        upperColName = "Start time"
        triggerCol = "ClickMe"

        ClickedInTable = Not (ActiveCell.ListObject Is Nothing)

        If ClickedInTable Then
            inTriggerCol = (GetColumnName() = triggerCol)
            If inTriggerCol Then

                inTableBody = Not (ActiveCell.ListObject.Range.row = ActiveCell.row)

                If inTableBody Then

                    Set lowerCell = Range(GetNeighborCell(lowerColName)).Offset(-1)
                    Set upperCell = Range(GetNeighborCell(upperColName))

                    lowerIsHeader = (lowerCell.row = ActiveCell.ListObject.Range.row)
                    If Not (lowerIsHeader) Then
                        lower = lowerCell.Text
                        upper = upperCell.Text

                        colToFilterRelativeIndex = ActiveSheet _
                            .ListObjects(tableToFilter) _
                            .ListColumns(colToFilter).index

                        ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tableToFilter).Range.AutoFilter _
                            Field:=colToFilterRelativeIndex, _
                            Criteria1:=">=" & lower, _
                            Operator:=xlAnd, _
                            Criteria2:="<=" & upper

                        ActiveCell.Value = lower & " - " & upper
                    Else
                        ActiveCell.Value = "N/A"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

And helper functions are

```
Function GetColumnName()
    Dim rowHeader As Integer
    Dim colCurrent As Integer
    Dim name As String
    rowHeader = ActiveCell.ListObject.Range.row
    colCurrent = ActiveCell.Column
    name = Cells(rowHeader, colCurrent).Value
    GetColumnName = name
End Function


Function GetNeighborCell(colName As String)
    Dim firstCol As Integer
    Dim offsetCol
    Dim col
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim val As String

    firstCol = ActiveCell.ListObject.Range.Column
    offsetCol = ActiveCell.ListObject.ListColumns(colName).index - 1
    col = firstCol + offsetCol

    row = ActiveCell.row
    val = Cells(row, col).Value
    GetNeighborCell = Cells(row, col).Address
End Function
```